# Handling exit/changes/etc from external editor in WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a WinRT app that, in part, does file downloads from an online service and manages the local copy of the files. When stored locally, the files need to be encrypted, but during editing/viewing, as that happens in external editors (office, pdf, etc) they need to be decrypted.

Is there a way within the WinRT API set to launch an external browser (ie. Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync) and somehow get notification when that app has been closed?

Right now, I can download and encrypt the file fine, but when I want to view it, I have to decrypt it and launch the external editor with no way of knowing (or even necessarily running again) when it's finished so I can re-encrypt the file.

Ideally I would like to somehow bind the external application to mine so that my app is unavailable until the external editor is closed, but would settle for notification when the app is closed or any other creative solutions.

Comment: You can have a button that says "click here when finish editing"

Comment: Thought of that already, but it's pretty error susceptible. If the user tasks back to my app before the editor is closed, I may or may not be able to delete the temporary file and then if I do, I would lose their changes and be open to the external editor then re-saving an unencrypted copy at a later time. Especially since some editors lock the source file and some don't.

Comment: Also, my app is suspended when the external editor is opened. Should the system decide to terminate my app the user won't even see it still running to go back and click "done". Even if it's not terminated, the user must still return to it and click "done" for the re-encryption to happen

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that. Have you thought of working with PDFs only and using a in-app PDF viewer control? ComponentOne has one in their library, but I haven't tried it and I don't know if it's any good. http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDFWinRT/

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support a full range of document types.

Answer (score 0):

Your app scenario looks something like skydrive app from Microsoft. It downloads files from the skydrive service, integrates with file open and file save pickers.

Try integrating with file picker contracts.

you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx). There are sample code also available to implement file picker contracts.

Comment: Looked also at file pickers, but the problem there is that the user would have to go open an external app and then choose to open a file from my app and then pick it. Since the flow starts from my app, this would be a horrible user experience.